# Saving user details to graphql database with AWS Amplify and a Cognito authentication flow

Tags: graphql, authorization, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

My website uses AWS Amplify and Cognito user pools to authenticate users. When someone submits the registration form on the site, they receive an email confirmation link. Their information is automatically added to the Cognito user pool.

I'd like to add this user's details to our AWS Amplify graphql database and also add them to the "Public" Cognito user group. (I think they must be in this group in order to use features in the website that mutate the graphql database).

I am considering how to add users to the graphql database. One option is to write a lambda function that does this when the user clicks the confirmation link, as described here: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cognito-add-user-to-group. Is this the best approach?

An alternative idea is to make our front end call this method of the AWS-amplify library when the user clicks submit on the registration form.

```
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUser, { input: user }))
```

However, this function is a mutation and therefore requires authorization. Since the user is not yet logged at this registration page, I would need to waive authorization on this function. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi GNG,
The best thing you can do is to write a lambda function triggered at the email confirmation.
You can use this lambda to publish user's information into an SNS topic and, on the other side, write other lambdas subscribed to this topic that could:
- Add user to database
- Add user to your newsletter service (es. Mailchimp, Sendinblue,..)
- etc.

Comment: ... because you don't want uncontrolled [massive] user creation (DOS)

Comment: @marco.santonocito great that is more or less what I ended up doing. By following this tutorial: https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-add-new-cognito-users-to-dynamodb-using-lambda-e3f55541297c